# Google map js API: map is not centered in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dafq8Lx5/4/) with google map on it, but marker is sticked to the bottom of the div:

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 map" id="loc-1">
        <div id="map1" class="user_map"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 12px sans-serif;
}
h1, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.user_map {
  padding-bottom: 58%;
  border: 2px solid #9F8F88;
}
```

**JS**

```
var map;
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        zoom: 14,
    });
    //google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = "1 Infinite Loop,Cupertino,CA,95014";
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: "{{ location.name }}"
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
            var zoom = map.getZoom();
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location, zoom);
        }
    });
});
```

How can I make it centered?

I've noticed, that `padding-bottom` rule directly affects it, but is it possible to achieve desired result without changing the CSS?

P.s. I've searched a lot of related questions, but it doesn't work in my case, so I clearly sure, that I miss something.

Comment: simply use `map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);`

Comment: Didn't help: http://jsfiddle.net/dafq8Lx5/6/

Comment: For me the marker is in the center in the linked fiddle

Comment: Tried in 3 browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Safari. It is on the bottom. Sent to other person, he also see it in the bottom

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dafq8Lx5/9/

Comment: Yeah, I see you've added event listener in geocoder success function. You can post it as answer, and I accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically  `results[0].geometry.location` already is a `LatLng`, you may use it directly for `setCenter`(remove the `zoom`-parameter, in v3 `setCenter` expects only a single argument):

```
 map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
```

The reason why it will still not work as expected (in the fiddle) is jsFiddle, they will resize the frames after the map has been created, but your script didn't recognize it.

As this may happen too  in your page you should trigger the `resize`-event of the map at the begin of the geocoding-callback.

[The final working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/dafq8Lx5/9/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a height to your map container:

```
.user_map {
    height: 300px;
}
```

If you can't change the CSS then do it with javascript:

```
document.getElementById('map1').style.height = '300px';
```

Comment: Thanks, looks promising

Answer (score -2):

you need to pass the latitude and longitude to a function in the google maps api.

in

```
map.setCenter();
```

you need to pass

```
new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude)
```

as integers

also at the position of the markers you will have to do the same

Comment: Didn't help. Changed everything below ```marker.setMap(map);``` according to your advise, but ```location``` atribute is the same LatLng object.

Comment: ok I'll need some more info, In your code, what does `results[0].geometry.location` return